# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/domain

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hello I'm using the following

hibernate-core-4.1.2.Final.jar

mysql-connector-5.1.6.jar

Both can be found in my project lib directory.

I have the following **hibernate.cg.xml** configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Defines the SQL dialect used in Hiberante's application -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!--Local Database Connection-->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/domain</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">test</property> 

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>  

        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="format_sql">false</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">ram</property> 
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and I'm getting the following exception.

```
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
 jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/domain     at
 java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)   at
 java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)   at
 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:192)
    at
 org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:278)
    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
    ... 145 more
```

I do not want to use JNDI do to the fact management wants to keep the app as portable as possible, so what am I missing to get this to work with jdbc? Am I required to do any kind of configurations to tomcat?

[image]

Tomcat Lib

[image]

Comment: I am having the same problem , were you able to find a solution to it ?

Comment: @PratikSinghal-ps06756 I do not remember how I fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

Try putting [mysql-connector-5.1.6.jar](https://code.google.com/p/find-ur-pal/downloads/detail?name=mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar&) directly into the **lib folder of tomcat** and restarting it.

Comment: I've tried adding mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar and then mysql-connector-java-5.1.27 to my tomcat lib directory and still not working.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried calling the driver class?:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

How to call it:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    // error out
}
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(/*your connection query*/);
```

I may have the class wrong, but if `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` doesn't work, you can also try `com.mysql.JDBC` or `com.mysql.jdbc` (basing off how SQLite calls it)

Comment: You simply call it when getting a connection object from the driver manager. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you edit the config to obscure the connection string?
Your hibernate config has a different database name than the error:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/domain</property>

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
 jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/etss
```

In terms of portability, I package the database driver with my war, so it is self contained. This makes for deployment across multiple environments much easier and if another developer wants to build and run locally, they just have to drop the war into Tomcat and go. Place the database driver in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Also, in terms portability, I recommend JNDI... that way you do not have to edit your hibernate config file when you deploy it to another server and it can stay packaged in your war. You just add the JNDI reference in the Tomcat config.

Comment: I typically change the project name when posting to stackoverflow, I must have missed that in the log. My company likes to move projects around to different servers thus the reason they do not want to use JNDI. 

Oddly enough, the driver does exist in my WEB-INF/lib folder which is why I don't understand why this isn't working. I upgraded the driver, so when viewing my domain/WB-INF/lib folder mysql-connector-java.5.1.27.jar is present.

Comment: I added some additional info to my question, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs because the mysql database driver is not on your classpath. Add it to your classpath to repair the issue. Since you are using tomcat you can simply add it to the **tomcat/lib** directory.

Comment: Did you place the driver in the tomcat lib dir? Not to be confused with your webapp web-inf lib dir.

Comment: Yes, I put mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar in my tomcat lib directory. I attached a screen shot of the lib directory to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting your drivers in/at where you have place JDK's Extension directory. Please see:http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/ErrorMessages.html#zz-4.1

Once that is done I would encourage you to from your prompt type:
echo %CLASSPATH%