# Not able to connect to XA datasource using JNDI

Tags: java, jndi, xa

I am trying to connect my java spring batch application to datasource using JNDI. My application requires XA datasource. I tried to configure normal datasource using below code and it seems to connect to it perfectly. But when i try to change the driver class to XA(oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource) it doesn't seem to connect.i tried changing the type to javax.sql.XADataSource. Can someone tell me if i need to set additional properties for XA connectivity ?

```
<Resource name="jdbc/DS-ref" 
                  auth="Container"
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                  username="user"
                  password="password"
                  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
                  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx"
                  initialSize="20"
                  maxWaitMillis="15000"
                  maxTotal="75"
                  maxIdle="20"
                  testOnBorrow="true"
                  validationQuery="select 1 from dual" />
```

If i change the code in context.xml, I get error saying " Name [jdbc/DS-ref] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]."

Context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/DS-ref" 
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.XADataSource"
              username="user"
              password="password"
             driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx"
              initialSize="20"
              maxWaitMillis="15000"
              maxTotal="75"
              maxIdle="20"
              testOnBorrow="true"
              validationQuery="select 1 from dual" />
```

web.xml

```
<resource-ref id="ResourceRef_CrcDataSource">
    <description></description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/DS-ref</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.XADataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
  </resource-ref>
```

datasource.java

```
 // Use JNDI via Spring
        Object tmpDs;
        setResourceRef(true); // Make "java:comp/env/" prefix optional
        try {
            log.debug("pJndiName" +pJndiName);
            tmpDs = lookup(pJndiName, DataSource.class);
            log.debug("tmpDs"+tmpDs);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            throw new RuntimeException("Error looking up DataSource via JNDI. jndiName: " + pJndiName, e);
        }

         if (null == tmpDs) {
            throw new RuntimeException("DataSource JNDI lookup returned null. jndiName: " + pJndiName);
        }
        if (!DataSource.class.isInstance(tmpDs)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Illegal class returned by DataSource JNDI lookup. " + "jndiName: "
                    + pJndiName + ", returned class: " + tmpDs.getClass().getName());
        }
        return (DataSource) tmpDs;
```

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving ?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver - this is the error

Comment: Which webserver are you using ?

Comment: we are using tomcat

Comment: http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Oracle-XA-datasource-configuration-td4671692.html can you try what is suggested in lin

Comment: You should make sure your JAVA Code is matching what you want to do. At the Moment it sounds just like an issue in your JAVA Code. Can you post your code where you try to open the XA connection?

Comment: @Jabir : Now I am getting a different error that says "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver"

Comment: @DavidJulitz  tmpDs = lookup(pJndiName, DataSource.class); this is how i am accesing the connection from jndi. And for XA,

Comment: Can you add more logs as this is very generic and it means it is unable to find the appropriate driver class.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806698/caused-by-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-loca check this URL for details

Comment: @Jabir The below error is followed by the earlier error i commented. Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Comment: What type is tmpDs? Probably tmpDs has the wrong type? This is at least what the first error said. You should check to use the right class *oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource* and not *java.sql.Driver*.

Comment: To make this more easy you should insert the full Information in your Question, like minimal sample Code showing the issue, probable error Messages and so on. Otherwise this is just a guessing game.

Comment: With the same code I am able to connect to normal DB. I am getting an issue only when I am connecting to XA Datasource with the mentioned driver class.The error wen I change the driver class to XA in the above mentioned code is "Name [jdbc/DS-ref] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]." @DavidJulitz

Comment: This seems to fix your issue already. Now you face another issue, Please show the complete Code above and then I can probably help.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code @DavidJulitz